# java skewed shape when rotated

Tags: java, graphics, awt, java-2d, rotational-matrices

So I have a shape and I want to rotate it with respect to the y-axis. I'm pretty sure my rotation matrix is correct, here's how the rotation matrix looks like in our guide:

[image]

And here's the code I implemented:

```
public static void rotate3Dy(float[] xCoords, float[] yCoords, float[] zCoords, float angle) {
    float cosine_angle = (float) Math.cos(angle);
    float sine_angle = (float) Math.sin(angle);

    for (int i = 0; i < yCoords.length; i++) {
        xCoords[i] = (xCoords[i] * cosine_angle) + (zCoords[i] * sine_angle) + 0;
        zCoords[i] = (-xCoords[i] * sine_angle) + (zCoords[i] * cosine_angle) + 0;
    }
}
```

Rotating the shape up/down/left/right alone looks fine, but when I rotate it either left or right after being rotated up/down it starts getting skewed.

[image]

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Comment: Namely, it's unclear 1) what figure you are talking about, 2) what exactly 'skewed' means, 3) how your other rotations are implemented, 4)  What up/down/left/right means in terms of x, y and z.

Comment: Why do you think anything's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the skew is caused by the following flaw in your rotation transform: In the loop of your `rotate3Dy`-method you transform `xCoords[i]` and then you use 
the **transformed** value to transform `zCoords[i]` instead of computing the latter with the **untransformed** value of `xCoords[i]`.

Try the following: Clone the `xCoords`-array before its transformation i.e. replace

```
    for (int i = 0; i < yCoords.length; i++) {
        xCoords[i] = (xCoords[i] * cosine_angle) + (zCoords[i] * sine_angle) + 0;
        zCoords[i] = (-xCoords[i] * sine_angle) + (zCoords[i] * cosine_angle) + 0;
    }
```

with

```
    float[] xCoordsTmp = xCoords.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < yCoords.length; i++) {
        xCoords[i] = (xCoordsTmp[i] * cosine_angle) + (zCoords[i] * sine_angle) + 0;
        zCoords[i] = (-xCoordsTmp[i] * sine_angle) + (zCoords[i] * cosine_angle) + 0;
    }
```

Maybe that fixes the problem.